# How to create a function that totals an order with several items?

Tags: sql, database

I need to create a function which will return the total of an order. I've been given three tables with the following variables

Table 1 - Order

- Order_ID
- Date_Placed
- Date_Fulfilled

Table 2 - Order Product

- Order_ID
- Product_ID
- Product_Quantity

Table 3 - Product

- Product_ID
- Price

I'm struggling to put together a coherent function. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've already attempted to set up the function with joins between both tables, but am unable to figure out where I should be putting my equation.

```
BEGIN

    SELECT order.order_id, SUM(product.price * order_item.quantity)
    FROM `order`
    JOIN `order_item` ON order.order_id = order_product.order_id
    JOIN `product` ON order_product.product_id = product.product_id;
END $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to take your select statement, and `group` it by your `order.order_id`. That way you'll have one row per order, with the `sum` total of that order.

```
SELECT order.order_id, SUM(product.price * order_item.quantity) as total_price
FROM `order`
JOIN `order_item` ON order.order_id = order_product.order_id
JOIN `product` ON order_product.product_id = product.product_id
GROUP BY order.order_id
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there anything that I need to do in order to make it a function instead of just a regular query? My understanding was that a function needs to be wrapped with DELIMITER on top and bottom, and BEGIN/END as well. Is that accurate?

Comment: @Colts2092 It will depend on which RDBMS you're using. A function definition in postgresql will be different than in oracle, and won't exist at all in Sybase. `BEGIN`/`END` in SQL is pretty standard for containing a block of SQL though. It's unlikely that you'll need to specify a DELIMITER when defining a function. Most RDBMSes use a `CREATE FUNCTION` command, so if you lookup a tutorial for creating functions with your RDBMS, you'll probably be able to follow along with that.

Answer (score 2):

You might be surprised, but the `orders` table is not needed for this query.  You can just aggregate off the other two tables:

```
SELECT oi.order_id, SUM(p.price * oi.quantity)
FROM order_item oi JOIN
     product p
     ON po.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY oi.order_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
SELECT order.order_id, SUM(product.price * order_item.quantity)
FROM order o,
JOIN order_item  oi,  
JOIN product p  where 
o.order_id = oi.order_id and
oi.product_id = p.product_id
group by order_product.product_id = product.product_id;
```